# How to use multithreading in foreach loop in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, foreach

I have a datatable that has 10000 rows, I use foreach loop to the datatable to get each row and for each row I call a function that takes 2 second to execute, and for 10000 rows total time is 20000 seconds, how can I use multithreading to improve the performance. Here is my code

```
DataTable AttCollection = getRecord();  // 10000 records
foreach (var ac in AttCollection)
            {
                AddAttendace(branchID, _ep.Get_V(ac.Key, true, null), ac.Value);
            }


public bool AddAttendace(int? branchID, V_HR_EmployeePlacementDetailed emp, DateTime dt) 
        {
            //code...
        }
```

Comment: You can get performance improvement of creating a dictionary to do look up instead of enumerating through every row.  Your average search time is N/2 while dictionary will be Log2(N).

Answer (score 4):

Easiest solution might be using [Parallel.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx).
Alternatively you can manually hand of the work to a threadpool (e.g. via `Task.Run()`) and wait for all the results at the end.

Be aware that your `AddAttendace` function must be thread safe for these optimizations.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Parallel.Foreach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001(v=vs.110).aspx), this will execute your foreach loop in a parallel manner using ThreadPool threads:

```
Parallel.Foreach(AttCollection, 
                    ac => AddAttendace(branchID, _ep.Get_V(ac.Key, true, null), ac.Value));
```

Note that you will need to ensure that AddAttendace method is thread safe because you will access it from multiple threads and you do not want to create any race conditions.

You should know that Parallel.Foreach does not guarantee how many threads will be used for the operation (if it will be 1 or more) but you can limit the number of threads for the operation using [ParallelOptions Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions(v=vs.110).aspx) and this [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783747(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
  Parallel.Foreach(AttCollection, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3 },
                    ac => AddAttendace(branchID, _ep.Get_V(ac.Key, true, null), ac.Value));
```

Comment: if the AddAttendace methos is not thread safe than what i should do?

Comment: If it isn't thread safe you shouldn't use it in a multithreaded environment, you should change it to be thread safe or just not use mulitple threads at all.

Comment: I dont know wether AddAttendace method is in safe thread or not, I have use Parallel.ForEach as

            Parallel.ForEach(AttCollection, ac =>
            {
                AddAttendace(branchID, _ep.Get_V(ac.Key, true, null), ac.Value);
            });

Comment: I suggest you to open another question about the thread safety of your method with all the relevant code.

Comment: And in _ep.Get_V(ac.Key, true, null) method i am getting random exceptions i.e
"
The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.",

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",

Comment: I think you've got your answer, your code is not thread safe.

Comment: ok if its not thread safe, than what alternative solution is for my problem in your mind, if you have got my problem

Comment: First you should consider if you have to use mulitple threads (performance issues maybe), and if you do need mulitple threads you should modify your code to work with mulitple threads in a safe way.

Answer (score 1):

Try Parallel.ForEach and wrap the current method in a Task.

Comment: Why? This is no better than a comment without a "why".